# NoReverseMatch at /judge/judge-timeslot.html Reverse for 'sub' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django

Running Django 2.0.1. Getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /judge/judge-timeslot.html Reverse for 'sub' 
    with arguments '('',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['judge\\/(?P<choice_id>[0-9]+)$']

Request Method: GET  
Django Version: 2.0.1  
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'judge'
urlpatterns = [
    path('judge-home.html', views.index, name='index'),
    path('judge-score.html', views.score, name='score'),
    path('judge-timeslot.html', views.timeslots, name='timeslots'),
    path('results.html', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:choice_id>', views.sub, name='sub'),
]
```

sub view in views.py:

```
def sub(request, choice_id):
template = loader.get_template("judge/judge-timeslot.html")
c = get_object_or_404(Choice, pk=choice_id)

try:
    selected_choice = c.choice_set.getlist(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the question voting form.
    return render(request, template, {
        'choice': c,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    # selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
    # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
    # user hits the Back button.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('judge/judge-timeslot.html', args=(c.id,)))
```

Here is the judge-timeslot.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'judge:sub' choice.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table--bordered table--highlight">
        <tbody>
            {% for slot in slots %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox", name="choice" id="choice {{forloop.counter}}"
                        value="{{choice.id}}"/>
                        <span class="checkbox__input"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>{{slot}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn--primary">Select</button>
</form>
```

It is referring to this line:

```
<form action="{% url 'judge:sub' choice.id %}" method="post">
```

But no matter what I change in urls.py nothing seems to work. 
Can someone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: This is not real code. `c.choice_set.getlist` would raise a NameError because `getlist` is a method of a QueryDict - eg `request.POST` - not of a Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
{% url 'judge:sub' choice.id %}
```

Your `choice.id` gives empty result

It's normal: you're making a loop here `{% for slot in slots %}` so this is the variable `slot` that you should use, not `choice`... try with `slot.id` instead of `choice.id`.

So Django tries to look for a view named '`sub`' that has nothing as parameters, and he saw that one: `path('<int:choice_id>', views.sub, name='sub'),` (that's exactly what your error told you)

Note for template debugging: try to display what's in `slot` like

```
{% if slot %}
    Slot is: {{ slot }}
{% else %}
    Slot is empty!
{% endif %}
```

And same for choice, put it before your "`form`" code:

```
{% if choice %}
    Choice is: {{ choice }}
{% else %}
    Choice is empty!
{% endif %}
```

Aside note: if you're new to Django, use PyCharm (pro version (you have free 30 days eval), maybe community free edition works too) and you can make breakpoints into your template file. Incredibly useful.

Comment: I see what you're saying, however I am new to Django and don't really know how to fix this issue. I was following the polls tutorial, so I don't understand why choice.id gives an empty result

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: slot.id yields the same error unfortunately. And thanks for the tip, I'll definitely look into that for this project!

Comment: Edited my answer again :)

Comment: you use "choice" at the very beginning, even before  the loop (sorry I didnt check your code properly), edited my answer again